# Firebase datasnapshot child returns null

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have a very strange problem. datasnapshot.val() returns null instead of child object.

```
firebase.database().ref().child('scores').child(currUser.uid).child(playerIds[$(playerSel).find("option:selected").val()-1])
        .child('0')//.child("2130903049‬")
        .on('value', snap => {
            console.log(snap.val());
            console.log(snap.child("2130903049‬").val());

        });
```

console:

> Object {2130903049: Object}
>
> null

EDIT:

now it started working correctly if I put "2130903049‬" directly in child() method. But if I take value from document.getElementById('mode').value it returns null again.

```
<select id="mode" class="form-control select sel select-inverse" data-toggle="select">
                    <option value="0" selected>Izberi postavitev</option>
                    <optgroup label="3 stožci">
                        <option value="‭2130903049‬">Trikotnik</option>
                        <option value="‭2130903044‬">Črta</option>
                    </optgroup>
                    <optgroup label="4 stožci">
                        <option value="‭2130903048‬‬">Kvadrat</option>
                        <option value="‭2130903045‬‬">Črta</option>
                        <option value="‭‭2130903047‬‬‬">Trikotnik</option>
                    </optgroup>
                </select>
```

> document.getElementById('mode').value
>
> "‭2130903049‬"

How is this possible?

> val = "2130903049"
>
> "2130903049"
>
> val2 = modeSel.value
>
> "‭2130903049‬"
>
> val == val2
>
> false

Comment: are you passing right parameters? double check all this `scores`, `currUser.uid`, `playerIds[$(playerSel)` and so on..

Comment: @Ashok paramaters must be correct because first console.log() returns an object that contains child "2130903049‬"

Comment: There is at least one non-visible, 'special' character at the end of the string you've passed to `child` and have assigned to `val`. Delete the strings (including the quotes) and type them in again.

Comment: @cartant That worked, thanks. I copied those numbers from windows calculator, obviously it adds some invisible characters.